# Understanding a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to see what the following group is: $(C_2)^3$ where $C_2$ is the cyclic group of order 2.

Now I don't know what exactly it represents . What are the elements of such a group?

Comment: if Im not wrong the elements of $(C_2)^3$ can be represented by binary numbers of length $3$.

Comment: If you want a formal description, its elements are triples and addition is pointwise. This group can be seen as the group of symmetries of the 3D space that are only allowed to switch one of the base vectors (i.e. $e_i$ is sent to $e_i$ or $-e_i$). It's a subgroup of the group of linear symmetries of the 3D space

Comment: Do you recognize that $(C_2)^3 = C_2\times C_2 \times C_2$, (also equivalent to $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to write it as and think of it as $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times\mathbb Z_2 $ so that each element is a triplet, $(a,b,c)$ where $a,b,c$ are each either $0$ or $1$.

So there are $2^3=8$ elements: $(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (0,1,1), (1,0,0),(1,0,1),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)$.

$(a,b,c)+(k,m,n)$ is defined as $(a+k, b+m,c+n)$ where $0+0 = 0; 1+0= 0+1= 1; 1+1= 0$.

The identity element is $(0,0,0)$ as $(a,b,c) + (0,0,0) = (0,0,0) + (a,b,c) = (a+0, b+0,c+0) = (a,b,c)$.

The inverse of $(a,b,c)$ is ... itself $(a,b,c)$ as $(a,b,c) = (a+a,b+b, c+c)$ and as $0 + 0 = 0$ and $1+1 = 0$ it must be that $(a+a, b+ b, c+c) =(0,0,0)$.

Furthermore:  If $e\ne f$ then either $e = 1; f = 0$ or $e= 0; f= 1$ so $e+f $ either equals $0 + 1 = 1$ or  equals $1+0 = 1$ so $e + f = 0 \iff e=f$.  So the inverse $-(a,b,c) = (a,b,c)$ is unique; i.e. $(a,b,c) + (k,m,n) = (0,0,0) \iff (a,b,c) = (k,m,n)$

Comment: If you felt obliged to do the askers homework for him/her upon his/her demand, you accomplished that task.  But I won't upvote such pandering answers.

Comment: I don't think this was a homework question.  It seemed to be a sincere conceptual confusion.

Comment: Indeed you've convinced yourself that you made a break-through for the asker;  People have many reasons for needing to believe what they want to believe. But I stand by my comment, as unpleasant it might be for you to consider.

Comment: Um... this an internet posting board.  Take a walk in the woods and get a perspective on the world.

Comment: huh?  You haven't addressed my comments.  If you choose not to, that's fine.  But don't try to use a red herring to change the topic.  Cheers!

Comment: Your comments and objections are truly obsessive and bizarre.

Comment: Your last comment, as your earlier are entirely irrelevant to the issue at hand.  All you've done is try to insult me.  But alas, others can read that for themselves.  Chill.

Comment: Wow.... all I can say is just ... wow.

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at it is as a 3 dimensional vector.  The operation is addition, and the field is $\mathbb Z_2$

$(0,0,0)$ will be the identity

$(1,0,0)$ will be one of the elements
$(1,0,0) +(1,0,0) = (0,0,0)$

$(1,0,0) = -(1,0,0)$ i.e. it is its own inverse.

Build out the rest, an prove that it meets the criteria of a group.

You could also do this as:

$a,b,c$ are generators.

Each generator is cyclic of order 2.
$a^2 = b^2 = c^2  =e$

And the group is Abelian.

Another way to look at is to think of a set of 3 switches, each is either on or it is off.

The group acts on this set to flip the switches.

Answer (score 0):

$C_2$ is the simplest non-trivial group and can be represented as the group of symmetries of the $0-$sphere consisting of the two points $(-1)$ and $(+1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. this simple symmetry may be regarded as a reflection.

the symbol $C_2^3$ denotes the direct product of three copies of $C_2$. you can visualize it by taking the three pairs of non-adjacent vertices of an octahedron as three 0-spheres, each acted on by exactly one of the three groups. imagine, for example, that there are LED lights at each vertex, with exactly one of each pair lit at any given time. $C_2^3$ can then be used to represent the ways of switching between the eight possible states.